# HyperX Cloud Alpha S USB headset mic not detected

Tags: usb, sound, microphone, headset

I just bought a new headset, a HyperX Cloud Alpha S. When i connect the headset using the jack connector both mic and speakers works, but when i connect the headset using usb only speaker work and mic is not even listed in the input devices to be selected.

[image: screenshot of audio device settings]

`alsamixer` shows results are like the following:

[image: screenshot of alsamixer]

My `alsa-base.conf` content are like the following:

```
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
alias sound-slot-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

I tried different models for `options snd-hda-intel model=` but without luck.

```
❯ lsmod | grep snd
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_usb_audio         258048  0
snd_usbmidi_lib        36864  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_rawmidi            36864  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_usbmidi_lib
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   118784  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          53248  9
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         131072  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,thinkpad_acpi
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
mc                     53248  5 videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
snd                    90112  32 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,thinkpad_acpi,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

My codec:

```
❯ cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec                                                                                                                               
Codec: Realtek ALC298
Codec: Nvidia GPU 60 HDMI/DP
```

In `pavucontrol` it show the mic as `unplugged`:

[image: screenshot of pavucontrol]

I tried the `hdajackretask` in which I don't know what to do, but whenever I try to "apply now" it fails with an error message.

Killing pulseaudio didn't work either.

[image: screenshot of Jack retasking for HDA Intel sound cards]

[image: screenshot of Device or resource busy error dialog]

The same headset works on other machines running windows, even dual boot to Windows on my machine and also works.

I don't understand why it cant recognize the mic, or why it should be that difficult in ubuntu to plug a mic and make it work.!!!

Can anyone help me get this mic detected by Ubuntu? I tried Ubuntu 19.10 Pop!_OS, and also Ubuntu 20.04. Same issue.

---

My system log when I plug-in the headset is the following:

```
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt kernel: [20240.864771] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt kernel: [20241.031041] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=16ed, bcdDevice=41.03
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt kernel: [20241.031046] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt kernel: [20241.031050] usb 1-5: Product: HyperX Cloud Alpha S
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt kernel: [20241.031052] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: Kingston
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt kernel: [20241.031054] usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 000000000001
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt kernel: [20241.064648] usb 1-5: 12:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 12)
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt kernel: [20241.069565] usb 1-5: 6:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 6)
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt kernel: [20241.072604] input: Kingston HyperX Cloud Alpha S Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.5/0003:0951:16ED.000A/input/input42
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt kernel: [20241.133163] hid-generic 0003:0951:16ED.000A: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [Kingston HyperX Cloud Alpha S] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input5
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5"
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 8 was not an MTP device
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt systemd[1766]: Reached target Sound Card.
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt systemd[1136]: Reached target Sound Card.
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1873]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Kingston HyperX Cloud Alpha S Consumer Control (/dev/input/event10)
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1873]: (**) Kingston HyperX Cloud Alpha S Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1873]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Kingston HyperX Cloud Alpha S Consumer Control'
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1149]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Kingston HyperX Cloud Alpha S Consumer Control (/dev/input/event10)
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1149]: (**) Kingston HyperX Cloud Alpha S Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1149]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Kingston HyperX Cloud Alpha S Consumer Control'
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt kernel: [20241.190989] usb 1-5: 12:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 12)
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt kernel: [20241.196025] usb 1-5: 12:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 12)
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt kernel: [20241.201054] usb 1-5: 12:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 12)
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt kernel: [20241.206641] usb 1-5: 12:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 12)
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1873]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event10 13:74 fd 94 paused 0
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1873]: (**) Kingston HyperX Cloud Alpha S Consumer Control: always reports core events
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1873]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event10"
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1873]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1149]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event10 13:74 fd 26 paused 1
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1149]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:74
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1873]: (II) event10 - Kingston HyperX Cloud Alpha S Consumer Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1873]: (II) event10 - Kingston HyperX Cloud Alpha S Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1873]: (II) event10 - Kingston HyperX Cloud Alpha S Consumer Control: device removed
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1873]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.5/0003:0951:16ED.000A/input/input42/event10"
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1873]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Kingston HyperX Cloud Alpha S Consumer Control" (type: KEYBOARD, id 14)
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1873]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ara"
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1873]: (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1873]: (II) event10 - Kingston HyperX Cloud Alpha S Consumer Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1873]: (II) event10 - Kingston HyperX Cloud Alpha S Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt kernel: [20241.215872] usb 1-5: 12:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 12)
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt kernel: [20241.224989] usb 1-5: 12:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 12)
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt kernel: [20241.230517] usb 1-5: 12:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 12)
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt kernel: [20241.235612] usb 1-5: 12:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 12)
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt kernel: [20241.242918] usb 1-5: 12:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 12)
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt systemd-udevd[18532]: controlC1: Process '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime restore 1' failed with exit code 99.
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5"
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 8 was not an MTP device
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt pulseaudio[1773]: Unable to load mixer: Invalid argument
Apr 24 22:26:24 vegegoku-lpt rtkit-daemon[1211]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 0 users.
Apr 24 22:26:25 vegegoku-lpt rtkit-daemon[1211]: Failed to make ourselves RT: Operation not permitted
Apr 24 22:26:25 vegegoku-lpt rtkit-daemon[1211]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Apr 24 22:26:25 vegegoku-lpt rtkit-daemon[1211]: Failed to make ourselves RT: Operation not permitted
Apr 24 22:26:25 vegegoku-lpt rtkit-daemon[1211]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Apr 24 22:26:25 vegegoku-lpt rtkit-daemon[1211]: Failed to make ourselves RT: Operation not permitted
Apr 24 22:26:25 vegegoku-lpt rtkit-daemon[1211]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Apr 24 22:26:25 vegegoku-lpt rtkit-daemon[1211]: Failed to make ourselves RT: Operation not permitted
Apr 24 22:26:25 vegegoku-lpt rtkit-daemon[1211]: Supervising 0 threads of 0 processes of 1 users.
Apr 24 22:26:25 vegegoku-lpt rtkit-daemon[1211]: Failed to make ourselves RT: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in kernel. It was fixed month ago. So I doubt it will be applied to ubuntu kernel. See https://lkml.org/lkml/2020/4/4/197

Comment: thank you for pointing this out, is there a way to apply this fix manually to see if it fixes my issue

Comment: i got my issue fixed, i used mainline to install kernel 5.7 rc3, and it fixed the problem, i lost my nvidia drivers, but also there was a patch to fix them and i was able to install them manually

Comment: Yep, It is working well on 5.7.

Comment: This bag now fixed in Ubuntu 20.04, because we are able to install hwe-edge kernel, which 5.8.0.

Comment: I am using Pop os 20.04, the bug is fixed but not reliable enough, sometimes the mic won't be detected sometime the speakers, sometimes both won't be detected, and sometimes it just works, I also noticed that this change every time I remove and reinject the headset until it no longer works even after force reload alsa.

Comment: I have the same issue with headset missing from time to time. I notice that trouble related to Google Chrome and Youtube especially. I think there is some issue between Chrome, Pulse Audio and  the driver. I still can't find a way to reproduce it well.