# Multiple kernel errors after updating to newest kernel

Tags: kernel, updates

So kernel 5.7 has a fix for my [headphones'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230235/hyberx-cloud-alpha-s-usb-headset-mic-not-detected)  mic not being detected. However, when booting into the kernel I get the following errors

`nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e000000
ucsi_ccg 0-ooo8: ic2_transfer failed -110
ucsi_ccg 0-ooo8: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110`

I've updated from 5.4.0-33-generic to 5.7.0-generic manually using dpkg with the files directly from the [Ubuntu kernel website](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.7/). I installed using the following files

`linux-headers-5.7.0-050700_5.7.0-050700.202005312130_all.deb
linux-headers-5.7.0-050700-generic_5.7.0-050700.202005312130_amd64.deb
linux-image-unsigned-5.7.0-050700-generic_5.7.0-050700.202005312130_amd64.deb
linux-modules-5.7.0-050700-generic_5.7.0-050700.202005312130_amd64.deb`

By doing

`sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

In a directory with only the four downloaded .deb files

Comment: This is normal. Installing unsupported mainline kernels can throw all kinds of errors. If the system works, you can ignore them.

Comment: I'm new to the world of Linux, how long does it take for a mainline kernel to be supported by Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu releases have specific kernel versions. The 5.7+ kernel  will be supported when Ubuntu 20.10 is released in October.

Comment: But some fixes can be backported earlier. I suggest reporting a bug to Launchpad. That may speed up this process.

Comment: I'll look into that. I'm curious, how would the users in the linked AskUbuntu post be able to get the kernel to install and work?

Comment: Not everyone has Nvidia ;-)

Comment: Haha, Nvidia always causing problems!

Comment: The drivers don't support this kernel yet either

Answer (score 0):

No way, dkms, virtualbox, nvidia etc. are not supportin' 5.7 kernel yet. Last working is 5.6.16. (Remember about UKUU.)