# HyperX Cloud Alpha S USB soundcard - low volume under Linux ("cannot get min/max values for control" error)

Tags: usb, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

recently I've bought HyperX Cloud Alpha S USB headphones and initially they weren't working at all under my Linux. First on Debian 9, then the same on fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04. I managed to make them detected and partially working by recompiling my kernel using the below instructions:

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/ch08s06.html

The recompiled kernel (5.4.60) contained the necessary patch:

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/ch08s06.html

mentioned here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1232926.

This helped in a way that the USB soundcard is now detected and the headphones and the microphone are working. However the maximum output volume of the soundcard is about 30%-40% of the output I get under Windows (where they work perfectly fine).

I have even updated the firmware from 4103 to 4104 (there is a standalone firmware updater for Windows available on HyperX website that adds support for PlayStation 4 and Nintendo Switch) but that didn't change anything.

What is also interesting, the older ones which my wife has (HyperX Cloud II) work fine under Linux. The headphones output from their USB soundcard is much louder than from HyperX Cloud Alpha S.

dmesg output right after plugging in HyperX Cloud Alpha S headphones:

```
[17009.433193] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[17009.561859] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=16ed, bcdDevice=41.04
[17009.561865] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[17009.561869] usb 1-1.2: Product: HyperX Cloud Alpha S
[17009.561872] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Kingston
[17009.561875] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[17009.570397] input: Kingston HyperX Cloud Alpha S Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.5/0003:0951:16ED.0004/input/input22
[17009.629496] input: Kingston HyperX Cloud Alpha S as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.5/0003:0951:16ED.0004/input/input23
[17009.629889] hid-generic 0003:0951:16ED.0004: input,hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [Kingston HyperX Cloud Alpha S] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2/input5
[17009.651530] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[17009.692516] usb 1-1.2: 12:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 12)
[17009.702533] usb 1-1.2: 6:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 6)
[17009.702981] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[17009.780138] usb 1-1.2: 12:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 12)
[17009.790251] usb 1-1.2: 12:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 12)
[17009.800252] usb 1-1.2: 12:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 12)
[17009.810499] usb 1-1.2: 12:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 12)
[17009.820626] usb 1-1.2: 12:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 12)
[17009.830127] usb 1-1.2: 12:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 12)
[17009.840124] usb 1-1.2: 12:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 12)
[17009.850264] usb 1-1.2: 12:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 12)
[17009.860513] usb 1-1.2: 12:0: cannot get min/max values for control 2 (id 12)
```

There is no such "cannot get min/max values for control" error when plugging in the HyperX Cloud II headphones.

When I run alsamixer, press F6 and select my Alpha S headphones as a soudcard, the alsamixer crashes:

```
$ alsamixer 
cannot load mixer controls: Invalid argument
```

Please help ;) I hate Linux for making me such issues when I don't have time/knowledge to solve them...

BONUS TIP: When I had troubles detecting the headphones after installing new kernel, I deleted `~/.config/pulse` folder to clear pulseaudio cache and it helped.

Comment: Same issue under Mint 20. For me it would sometimes crash video playing capability (videos would load, but freeze until re-plugged USB), then syslog would get flooded with "usb 1-2: 3:1: usb_set_interface failed (-71)" and "usb 1-2: cannot submit urb 0, error -2: endpoint not enabled" messages.